# All mail sent from mail() goes to Spam yet correct headers etc

Tags: php, html

I've been doing a lot of reading up on this yet still can't find a solution. I'm building a site that sends a voucher by email to it's users once they've submitted a form. The problem I'm having is that the mail sent by the script is being screened by spam filters as being spam, yet it isn't as it's user submitted. This is the script I'm using:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(0); 

include("/home/users/web/b2243/moo.wheree/inc/event.inc"); 
include("/home/users/web/b2243/moo.wheree/inc/ad.inc"); 

$boundary = md5(time()) . "-2"; 
$eol = "\r\n"; 
$subject = "Tonights wheree voucher - $offer"; 

$fromaddress = "no-reply@wheree.co.uk"; 
$fromname = "wheree"; 

$headers = ''; 
$headers .= "Message-ID: <".time()."-".$fromaddress.">" . $eol; 
$headers .= "Date: ".date('r'). $eol; 
$headers .= "From: ".$fromname. "<".$fromaddress.">" . $eol; 

$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$fromname. "<".$fromaddress.">" . $eol; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: ".$fromname."<".$fromaddress.">" . $eol;

$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" .phpversion(). $eol; 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$boundary\"" . $eol . $eol; 

$headers .= "This is a MIME-formatted message.". $eol . $eol; 

$msg = ''; 

//text 
$msg .= "--" . $boundary . $eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=gb2312" . $eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: INLINE" . $eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Description: INLINE Description;" . $eol; 
$msg .= strip_tags(str_replace("<br>", "\n", $rBody)); 
$msg .= $eol . $eol; 

//html 
$msg .= "--" . $boundary . $eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;" . $eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: INLINE" . $eol; 
$msg .= "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">" . $eol; 
$msg .= 'Message Contents' . $eol; 
$msg .= $eol . $eol; 

$mail_sent = mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers, "-f no-reply@wheree.co.uk"); 

// Check if Mail is sent 
if ($mail_sent) 
include("/home/users/web/b2243/moo.wheree/inc/sent.php"); 
else { 
echo "<br> Message not sent, <a href="/">have another go</a>.<br>"; 
} 

?>
```

The site is hosted on a shared hosting plan, could this be the problem? I've also heard about reverse DNS? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe you are already blacklisted as spammer? You may try to send yourself a mail. Sometimes the anti-spam-tools leaves additional headers, that gives you a hint, why they think you spam.

Comment: It's unlikely since the site hasn't launched yet.

Comment: Shared hosting is never good for serious sites, better to go with dedicated then you know your in control of all the issues.

Comment: Shared hosting seemed like a good idea at the time.

Comment: I work for a company that also does web hosting as a reseller through another company. We've had issues on more than one occasion where our client would get an IP on one of the shared hosts just to find out that it had been blacklisted already because it got caught up in a block ban because of one of its "neighbors". Might be worth looking into some of the blacklist checkers.

Comment: See also: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: Even with a dedicated server with a static IP, the first thing you should do is check that IP through various blacklists. It could well have just been used by a spammer immediately prior to it being reassigned to your new shiny server. I've had blacklisted IPs assigned to me by dedicated server companies twice (out of about 15, so what's that, about 13% of the time).

Comment: Ryan: *"It's unlikely since the site hasn't launched yet."* That doesn't mean the *previous* user of the IP wasn't blacklisted. Or if this is a real shared hosting system with multiple users of the same IP, one of the others could have got themselves listed.

Comment: Oh, and btw: check if it's not your mail client's spam filter at work here - if your message looks the way your code suggests, I'm pretty sure it would end up in my Spam bin. The spam filters also look at the message content, so sending a message which doesn't look like spam might help. (`no-reply` and no content? Yup, smells like spam)

Comment: I agree with the answers above regarding the shared server/ip issues and blacklisting, and would like to note that some spam filters will check that you have valid spf and/or DKIM entries in your DNS records.

Comment: The IP hasn't been black listed. The message I'm actually sending out, the voucher, wasn't included as I've tried both and it didn't make a difference, so I deemed the contents irrelevant for now. I'll have a go changing the sender address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a **lot** of things this could be. Shared hosting could well be an issue, yes; check your server's IP on blacklist lookup tools such as http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx. (And that's not just relevant to shared hosting, can happen with dedicated hosting as well — of 15-20 IPs I've been assigned with a new dedicated server over the years, at least 2 were already on blacklists. It's now the first thing I check when I get a new server.) It may help to set up [SPF](http://www.openspf.net/Project_Overview) on your domain to explicitly list that IP as being a valid sender (whether the receiving mail server and client check or trust SPF is down to the receiving mail server and client, but it's *something*; it's unlikely to override an active blacklist record, though).

These days, running a mail server is a pretty big pain in the rear. I long ago opted to spend a tiny amount of money per year to outsource it (in my case, with [Runbox](http://www.runbox.com/)). My code sends through their SMTP server rather than one I administer myself. In my particular case, I only *send* through them (I don't do any automated processing on received email, so I just have them go to Google Apps) but you can both send and receive with all the usual protocols. It's worked a treat for me, reducing the hassle factor tremendously. There are lots of other companies that will do the mail services for you as well, I'm not writing a commercial for this specific one, just for the concept.

Comment: The IP isn't black listed after checking the the tool you provided. I'm looking into a service like Runbox now, thank you.

Comment: @RyanBrodie: That's good news, anyway. :-) Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending from a shared hosting account there are two important things you should know.

1. There can potentially be up to thousands of domains hosted on the same IP address as your website. Whatever all those other sites do with e-mail is beyond your control and the IP could easily be on several blacklists for "shady activity" by those other sites.
2. As you already mentioned, some mailservers do a reverse lookup of the IP address of your sending mailserver. If it doesn't match your domain name (which it won't), this might be considered as "suspicious" by anti-spam tools.

The best you can do is let your users/members know that they should whitelist your domain on their mail servers/clients to improve the chance of delivery. If that's not good enough, you should seriously consider some dedicated hosting solutions like a VPS, dedicated server or even your own PI space.

Comment: The site's IP isn't black listed after just running a quick check on [mxtoolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx). That is an option but I can't guarantee that users will check their Spam box even if we tell them to, then we have to deal with the support fallout.